# eloquent guardar registro en tablas relacionadas en laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Necesito guardar un registro que involucra a 3 tablas en mi base de datos utilizando eloquent, la pregunta es: como puedo guardar un nuevo registro utilizando a los modelos relacionados junto con eloquent???.
la relacion es la siguiente un cliente le pertenece a un usuario y un usuario tiene relacion con un cliente
un cliente le pertenece a una compania y una compania tiene relacion con un cliente.
Dejo mi codigo a continuacion:

tabla client

```
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {             
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();          
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();

            $table->string('direccion', 80)->nullable();
            $table->string('ciudad', 80)->nullable();
            $table->string('provincia', 80)->nullable();
            $table->string('codigo_postal', 80)->nullable();
            $table->string('pais', 80)->nullable();
            $table->string('telefono_contacto', 30)->nullable(); 

            //Relation
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');   

            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');   
        });           

    }
```

modelo client

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'company_id', 'direccion', 'ciudad', 'provincia', 'codigo_postal', 'pais', 'telefono_contacto'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
}
```

modelo user

```
 public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
    }
```

modelo company

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
    }
```

aca mi clientcontroller 
estoy intentando esto pero no me funciona

```
 public function store(ClientStoreRequest $request)
    {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {                        
            $client = Client::create([
                'telefono_contacto' => $request['telefono_contacto'],
                'direccion'         => $request['calle'],
                'ciudad'            => $request['ciudad'],
                'provincia'         => $request['provincia'],
                'codigo_postal'     => $request['codigo_postal'],
                'pais'              => $request['pais']
            ]);

            $client->user()->create([
                'name'     => $request['nombre_cliente'],
                'surname'  => $request['apellido'],
                'email'    => $request['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),          
            ]);

            $client->company()->create([
                'nombre'            => $request['nombre_empresa'],
                'registro_fiscal'   => $request['registro_fiscal'],
                'sitio_web'         => $request['sitio_web'],
                'telefono'          => $request['telefono'],                   
            ]);            
        });       

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Cliente agregado con exito.']);   

    }
```

este es el error que recibo:

```
 "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `clients` (`telefono_contacto`, `direccion`, `ciudad`, `provincia`, `codigo_postal`, `pais`) values (34245678675, , , , , ))",
```

espero su pronta ayuda gracias!!!

Comment: Por como tienes hechas las relaciones, antes de crear un Client, ya debes tener el User y Company a los que pertenecerá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta enviar la solicitud de esta manera:

```
$client = Client::create([
            'id_cliente' =>'0',
            'telefono_contacto' => $request['telefono_contacto'],
            'direccion'         => $request['calle'],
            'ciudad'            => $request['ciudad'],
            'provincia'         => $request['provincia'],
            'codigo_postal'     => $request['codigo_postal'],
            'pais'              => $request['pais']
        ]);
```

Si el campo es auto-incrementable.

Answer (score 1):

El error es a nivel Base de Datos, y te dice que estás intentando insertar una fila en la tabla 'clients' sin pasarle el valor para el campo 'user_id' y ese campo no tiene configurado un valor por omisión.
Por como tienes hechas las relaciones, antes de crear un Client, ya debes tener el User y Company a los que pertenecerá. Entonces crea primero User y Company, para que al momento de crear Client, ya tengas las id para llenar los campos respectivos.

```
        $user = User::create([
            'name'     => $request['nombre_cliente'],
            'surname'  => $request['apellido'],
            'email'    => $request['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),          
        ]);

        $company = Company::create([
            'nombre'            => $request['nombre_empresa'],
            'registro_fiscal'   => $request['registro_fiscal'],
            'sitio_web'         => $request['sitio_web'],
            'telefono'          => $request['telefono'],                   
        ]);
```

Una vez que tienes User y Company, puedes crear un Client.

1. Directamente, pasándole las id de User y Company:

   ```
       $client = Client::create([
            'telefono_contacto' => $request['telefono_contacto'],
            'direccion'         => $request['calle'],
            'ciudad'            => $request['ciudad'],
            'provincia'         => $request['provincia'],
            'codigo_postal'     => $request['codigo_postal'],
            'pais'              => $request['pais'],
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'company_id' => $company->id
       ]);
   ```

Si quieres hacerlo a partir de la relación client(), que está presente en ambos modelos, User y Company.

2. A partir de una instancia de User (deberás pasarle el valor para el campo company_id y del campo user_id se ocupará de llenarlo Eloquent):

   ```
       $client = $user->client()->create([
            'telefono_contacto' => $request['telefono_contacto'],
            'direccion'         => $request['calle'],
            'ciudad'            => $request['ciudad'],
            'provincia'         => $request['provincia'],
            'codigo_postal'     => $request['codigo_postal'],
            'pais'              => $request['pais'],
            'company_id' => $company->id
       ]);
   ```
3. A partir de una instancia de Company (deberás pasarle el valor para el el campo user_id y del campo company_id se ocupará Eloquent):

   ```
       $client = $company->client()->create([
            'telefono_contacto' => $request['telefono_contacto'],
            'direccion'         => $request['calle'],
            'ciudad'            => $request['ciudad'],
            'provincia'         => $request['provincia'],
            'codigo_postal'     => $request['codigo_postal'],
            'pais'              => $request['pais'],
            'user_id' => $user->id
       ]);
   ```

---

**Para la opción 2**

```
$user = User::create([
    'name'     => $request['nombre_cliente'],
    'surname'  => $request['apellido'],
    'email'    => $request['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),          
]);

$company = Company::create([
    'nombre'            => $request['nombre_empresa'],
    'registro_fiscal'   => $request['registro_fiscal'],
    'sitio_web'         => $request['sitio_web'],
    'telefono'          => $request['telefono'],                   
]);  

$client = $user->client()->create([
    'telefono_contacto' => $request['telefono_contacto'],
    'direccion'         => $request['calle'],
    'ciudad'            => $request['ciudad'],
    'provincia'         => $request['provincia'],
    'codigo_postal'     => $request['codigo_postal'],
    'pais'              => $request['pais'],
    'company_id' => $company->id
]);
```

Comment: si lo que busco es hacerlo a partir de la relación tengo una duda respecto a tu sugerencia. Es necesario instanciar al modelo algo así como $client = Client::create ([]);?

Comment: No no, de las 3 opciones que puse, tenés que elegir una. Las 2 últimas opciones serían para crearlo a partir de la relación. Nota que al hacer ->client() sobre la instancia de un modelo User o Company, te estarás refiriendo al modelo Client. No sé si eso es lo que me preguntas?

Comment: @–porloscerros Ψ  de las 3 opciones que me sugeriste probe con la opcion 2 y al momento de completar mi formulario me sale este error ```"message": "Undefined variable: user"``` por eso te preguntaba si hay que instanciar al modelo User como te decia en mi comentario anterior

Comment: antes de crear Client con cualquiera de las 3 opciones debe asignar una instancia de User a la variable $user, ej `$user = User::create([//...]);` y una instancia de Company a la variable $company, ej `$company = Company::create([//...]);`

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta toda la secuencia por si no se entiende. **Primero creas un User** y lo asignas a la variable $user. **Segundo creas un Company** y lo asignas a la variable $company. **Tercero creas Client** a partir de la instancia de User que acabas de crear y asignar a la variable $user. Si lo haces así no te puede decir que $user no está definida.

Comment: gracias  @-porloscerros Ψ funciono perfecto!!! pregunto por curiosidad hay alguna otra manera de poder optimizar aun mas el codigo de la opcion 2?? aprovechando mis relaciones junto con eloquent

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz me alegra que te haya servido. No sé a que te refieras con optimizar, por lo que veo, no hay muchas opciones, salvo usar otro método, pero no me parece que optimice nada, solo cambias el método. Para este tipo de relación Uno a Uno, para insertar en BD tienes tres métodos: `save()`, `create()` y `associate()`. Puedes ver los ejemplos en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).

Comment: Me refería a esto no lo he probado todavía: User::create ($request=all()); lo mismo con company Company::create ($request=all()); y finalmente $client=$user->client()->create ([...]); Después lo probaré si funciona simplifica bastante el código

Comment: Podría ser, pero... Por un lado, no creo que funcione, pues deberían coincidir las claves del array del request con los campos de los modelos, y por lo que veo, no es así. Y por otro lado, tal vez son menos líneas de código, pero en cuestión de optimización del sistema creo que sería negativo, pues le estarías pasando datos de más a cada método create().

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz otra cosa que nada que ver.. pero veo que marcaste como aceptada una respuesta que en mi humilde opinión ni siquiera es una respuesta, sino solo una sugerencia de que intentes un código sin niguna explicación, además ese código ni siquiera tiene sentido, ni creo que funcione. Tené en cuenta que tanto preguntas como respuestas quedan registradas y aparecen en las búsquedas cuando otros programados tienen un problema similar y están buscando una solución, por lo que respuestas erradas generan confusión.

Comment: Si estás dispuesto a cambiar el frontend para que las claves coincidan con los campos de los modelos (ej: en vez de `'direccion' => $request['calle'],` que la clave sea dirección `'direccion' => $request['direccion'],`) se me ocurre que podrías hacer algo como lo que comentas `Company::create ($validated_data);`

Comment: OK lo tendré en cuenta en el transcurso del día lo probaré... gracias